# XML, JSON, YAML, or CSV for storing articles on server?

Tags: json, xml, csv, yaml

Please help me decide between the following formats for storing articles on a server:

- XML
- JSON
- YAML
- CSV

There are too many and I don't have the knowledge to choose.  **I am looking for objective criteria, not subjective opinions.**

The articles may contain a short title, some paragraphs and images.

Comment: This question is both too broad and too opinion based.  There are working systems out there that use any or all of the technologies you use.  If you have a  more specific question that isn't opinion based, it would be more appropriate here.  You might do well to research document DBs such as Mongo or Couch or Azure DocumentDB.

Comment: I've tried to salvage this question from its original form that asked for "preferences," which would be too opinion oriented.  Consider retracting your close vote (or voting to re-open if I finished too late).  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### XML vs JSON vs YAML vs CSV

Here are some considerations you might use to guide your decision:

**Choose XML if**

- You have to represent mixed content (tags mixed within text).  [*This would appear to be a major concern in your case.  You might even consider HTML for this reason.*]
- There's already an industry standard XSD to follow.
- You need to transform the data to another XML/HTML format.  (XSLT is great for transformations.)

**Choose JSON if**

- You have to represent data records, and a closer fit to JavaScript is valuable to your team or your community.

**Choose YAML if**

- You have to represent data records, and you value some additional features missing from JSON: comments, strings without quotes, order-preserving maps, and extensible data types.

**Choose CSV if**

- You have to represent data records, and you value ease of import/export with databases and spreadsheets.